# Parking lots details in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an application in Android where I need to display the parking lot details between the source and destination. I have already spent long time in finding any source where I can get the latitude and longitude of parking lots but got no success.

Can anyone please suggest me any URL to get the parking lot details?

Thanks in advance,

Aagrah

Comment: could you be a bit more specific what you mean with "parking lot details"?

Comment: There are 196 country in this world, Each country approximately have 100 to 150 city. Each city have at least 10,000,000 Parking lot. Now which one you are talking about? I don't know. So I can't answer this...

Comment: I understand you need this for an Android application but this question really isn't programming or android specific.

Answer (score 2):

Such datasets are usually commercial and not cheap.  You can try open streetmap instead

Comment: Thanks Konstantin Pribluda for providing me the details..